How we restrict service account to create/share docs in our domain only
How we restrict service account to create/share docs in our domain only ? we have few custom integration app with Google workspace to create docs/sheets, while create docs through apps, its default sharing policy is "shared with anyone with the link". How do we restrict it with Domain.
We want to restrict the general share policy to internal domain only, it should not share publicly.
